# Node js: How to set aws cloudwatch alarm state

Tags: alarm, cloudwatch

Tried with below lambda function which will change the state of alarm "OnSNSFailureArm".

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    var params = {
        AlarmName: 'OnSNSFailureArm',
        StateReason: 'Change Dynamically',
        StateValue: "INSUFFICIENT_DATA"
    };
cloudwatch.setAlarmState(params, function(err, data) {
 if (err){
 console.log(err, err.stack);  
 context.done();
  }  
  else{
   console.log(data);  
   context.done();
  }    
 });
};
```